# How to add QBE filters to SQL statement

Tags: php, mysql

I have been happy just adding an if statement here and there to a page on my site to produce a data list but now its in the 000's of lines of code and its messy.

I'm sure there is a better logic to what I am doing so any help would be good.

This is my logic (or how is should work)

```
check access lvl and add to sql - `accesslvl` = '1' 
Check if get_status is set - if set add to sql
check if get_product is set - if set add to sql
check if get_compnay is set - if set add to sql
check if get_datefrom is set - if set add to sql
check if get_dateto is set - if set add to sql
```

run query

now i have used lots of nested divs to work out if the gets are set, and if not dont and them to the sql, also it has to work out weather a WHERE or AND is needed.

I found this post [creating a mysql search string dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1424641/creating-a-mysql-search-string-dynamically)

And I was thing maybe this could help but not sure.
Example of my code.

```
if (isset($_GET['product'])&& $_GET['product'] >0){
        $product = $_GET['product'];
        if($a == 1){
            $sql_fields ="WHERE `Status_ID` = '$status' AND `Product` = '$product'";
        }
        else {
                $sql_fields ="WHERE `Product` = '$product'";
        }
        $b++;
    }
if (isset($_GET['company'])&& $_GET['company'] >0){
        $company = $_GET['company'];
        if($a == 0 && $b == 0){
                $sql_fields ="WHERE `Company_ID` = '$company'";
            }
        else if($a == 0 && $b == 1){
            $sql_fields ="WHERE `Product` = '$product' AND `Company_ID` = '$company'";
        }
        else if($a == 1 && $b == 0){
            $sql_fields ="WHERE `Status_ID` = '$status' AND `Company_ID` = '$company'";
        }
        else {
                $sql_fields ="WHERE `Status_ID` = '$status' AND `Product` = '$product' AND `Company_ID` = '$company' ";
        }
        $c++;
    }
if ($a == 0 && $b == 0 && $c == 0){
        $sql_fields =" ";
    }
if (isset($_GET['date_from']) && $_GET['date_from'] >0 && isset($_GET['date_to'])&& $_GET['date_to'] >0){
        if ($access_level == 1){
            if ($a == 0 && $b == 0 && $c == 0){
            $search_date = "WHERE `Date_added` >= '$date_from' AND `Date_added` <= '$date_to'";
            }
            else {
            $search_date = "AND `Date_added` >= '$date_from' AND `Date_added` <= '$date_to'";
            }
    }
if ($access_level ==2 or $access_level ==3){
            if ($a == 0 && $b == 0 && $c == 0){
            $search_date = " `Date_added` >= '$date_from' AND `Date_added` <= '$date_to'";
            $and = "AND";
            }
            else {
            $search_date = " `Date_added` >= '$date_from' AND `Date_added` <= '$date_to'";
            $and = "AND";
            }
        }

    }
else {
        $search_date = "";
        $and = "";
}
```

Here is my revised code!

```
$fields = array();

if (isset($_GET['status']) && $_GET['status'] >0){
    $status = $_GET['status'];
    $fields['Status_ID']= $_GET['status'];
    }
if (isset($_GET['product']) && $_GET['product'] >0){
    $product = $_GET['product'];
    $fields['Product_ID']= $_GET['product'];
    }
if (isset( $_GET['company']) && $_GET['company'] >0){
    $company = $_GET['company'];
    $fields['Company_ID']= $_GET['company'];
    }
if (isset( $_GET['closer']) && $_GET['closer'] >0){
    $closer = $_GET['closer'];
    $fields['Closer']= $_GET['closer'];
    }
if (isset( $_GET['date_from']) && $_GET['date_from'] >0 && isset( $_GET['date_to']) && $_GET['product'] >0){
    $date_from = $_GET['date_from'];
    $date_from = $_GET['date_to'];
    }
$field_count = count($fields);
if ($field_count == 0){
    $sql = "";
}
else {
    $field_count --;
    $sql="";
    $i=0;
        foreach($fields as $k => $v) {
            if($i==0){
                $sql = "WHERE `$k`  = '$v'";
                }
            else{
            $sql .=" AND `$k`  = '$v'";
            }
    $i++;

    }
}
 echo $sql;
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample for your code? How many things is it checking?

Comment: Please explain what it mean of `if set add to sql` ?

Comment: @nine7ySix think i have gone a very long way around this problem :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, there's no need for the conditional branches to determine the right SQL keyword to use (just use the joining keyword as the state variable instead). Also your code is vulnerable to SQL injection and may result in queries not using indexes effectively. Consider:

```
$join='WHERE';
$sql_filter='';
// potentially te following field meta data could be stored in a DB or file...
// or even selectively overriden at run time by the request...
$qbe=array(
   array('get_name'=>'product',
         'db_name'=>'Product',
         'op' => '=',
         'type'=>'string'),
   array('get_name'=>'date_from',
         'db_name'=>'date_added',
         'op' => '>=',
         'type' =>'date'),
   array('get_name'=>'date_to',
         'db_name'=>'date_added',
         'op' => '<=',
         'type' =>'date')
   ....
);
foreach ($qbe as $f) {
    $sql_filter=add_filter($sql_filter, $join, $f['get_name'],
      $f['type'], $f['op'], $f['db_name']);
}

function add_filter($sql_filter, &$join, $get_name, $type, $op, $db_name)
{
   $mod_filter=$sql_filter;
   if ($_GET[$get_name]) {
      switch(upper($type)) {
         case 'DATE':
            $mod_filter=$mod_filter 
              . " $join $db_name $op " 
              . date(strtotime($_GET[$get_name]), 'YmdHis');
            break;
         case 'NUMBER':
            $match=array();
            if (preg_match('/([-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+([eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?)/', $_GET[$get_name], $match) {
              $mod_filter=$mod_filter 
              . " $join $db_name $op " . $match[0];
            }
            break;
         default:
            $mod_filter=$mod_filter . " $join $db_name $op '" .
                mysql_real_escape_string($_GET[$get_name]) . "'";
            break;
      }
      if ($mod_filter != $sql_filter) {
           $join='AND';
      }
      return $mod_filter;
   }
```

Comment: I have created this (which is a lot less than before) what do you think.

Comment: Still has issues with SQL injection and inefficient use of indexes.

Answer (score 2):

> now i have used lots of nested divs to work out if the gets are set

Mixing html, php and sql in one script is a tried and tested recipe for spaghetti code. If you dont want to fully separate the HTML and the PHP at least

- put the PHP logic on top of your script and
- sanitize all given input
- build the where conditions
- query the database

and then only render the HTML parts by outputting the db results in the appropriate places. Dont put any of the above logic into the HTML part of the script.

As for your conditional logic to build the where clause: I have no clue what it does. I looked at it for 30 seconds but the code is poorly formatted and has variables like $a, $b and $c with magic numbers. You should pick a consistent coding style with proper indentation and formatting. And you should name your variables appropriately and minimize magic numbers with constants or function calls. This will make the code much more readable in the long run. And you (and other developers) will be able to understand what's going on much more easily.

Comment: I will go away and revise this code, then see what i come back with !